# Is there a pithy adjective for "shedding profusely"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm currently cat-tonguing looking for a word to describe something or someone that sheds a lot of hair; my instincts went with dis-/ex-pilitive/-pilious, but those entries are null in the dictionary.

Examples:

1. People with dander allergies usually can't keep ___ pets.
2. My ___ roommate is constantly clogging one drain or the other.

Comment: `My shedding or mo(u)lting roommate`

Comment: These aren't words which mean *shedding* a lot of hair, so I'll leave them as a comment rather than an answer, but there are a couple of obscure and funny words which mean *having* a lot of hair (i.e. being hairy): ***hirsute*** and ***flocculent*** (the latter being closer to *wooly*, so tight, curly, hair).

Comment: **flocculent** is a good one, thanks. Maybe expilious is my best choice after all!

Comment: *cat-tonguing*?

Comment: Mangy sometimes works.

Comment: Well, *furry* implies that.

Answer (score 4):

Animals ***moult*** (so the word you want is *moulting* in both instances).

To apply that verb to humans is usually humorous.

> (Of an animal) shed old feathers, hair, or skin to make way for a new growth
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moult)

Comment: (I once had a roommate who was almost furry, but he was scrupulously careful about not blocking plugholes.)

Comment: I had thought of molt/molting, but it's unsatisfactory for a few reasons: 1) I always associated "molt" with skin/feathers, though the definition shows hair is clearly suitable; 2) "molting" hits me immediately as a verb usage-- "my molting roommate" evokes a roommate in the process of molting, i.e., actively shedding skin (though context _helps_ clarify the usage); 3) I don't get the feeling that "molting" has any connotation of the _quantity_ of hair, which is central.

Comment: Perhaps a repurposing of `molting` would do, something like _moltative_ / _moltuous_ / _moltariffic_ that conveys the meaning through emphasis.

Comment: Well, having owned a cat which shed hair everywhere each Spring, I think *moulting* is fine. The point is that using *moulting* is humorous: animals moult, not humans [it's not really seemly to discuss losing body hair like fur]; animals only moult when the weather warms up and they don't need a thicker winter coat [whereas your roommate is moulting continuously].

Comment: Still, the emphasis should be on _quantity_, which _molting_ misses--both poodles and golden retrievers molt, but one is much more of a hassle to have than the other (in this regard). My word would differentiate these two.

Comment: In that case you should put the distinction in the question. As I've no experience of dogs, I wouldn't know which was which. And actually, *moulting* **does** indicate quantity: it's "an amount corresponding to seasonal loss; far more than normal day-to-day amounts".

Comment: I thought "a lot of" in the title would suffice, though I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Quite. But "a lot of hair" is "more than a few strands" where humans are concerned, surely?

Answer (score 1):

I have heard **balding** used to refer to humans losing significant amounts of hair.

Comment: I agree that this could be used to the effect I'm after--"Joe, this sink is disgusting, please clean up after your balding self!" On the other hand, it doesn't fit with "You're very ___", which an ideal choice would (i.e., ideal for what I'm after).